# Erro no Captcha com Magento: Call to a member function getBlockName

Tags: magento, captcha

Gerencio uma loja virtual, o site está fora do ar e quando vou acessar o administrador dá este erro:

> Call to a member function getBlockName() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43

Comment: Você instalou algum plugin recentemente? Está usando algo que não usou antes? Já conseguiu acessar antes

Comment: nada de novo foi feito (pelo menos não foi solicitado), sou leiga nisso e estou sem suporte da agencia responsável ou seja, desesperada! Isso é só com programador mesmo, ne?

Comment: Sim, mas nenhum programador será capaz de resolver com tão pouca informação, de qualquer maneira vou pesquisar ver se houve algum problema semelhante. Tente as respostas abaixo por enquanto.

Comment: brigada Guilherme!

Comment: me diz uma coisa, você tem APC instalado no seu servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Tente limpar os diretórios `var/cache` e `var/session`

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se que sua pasta /var tem permissão adequada.

Quando os captcha são criados eles primeiro são armazenados na pasta var. Devido a permissão imprópria não será salva. Isto irá retornar um objeto NULL, portanto, esse erro.

Comment: realmente é interessante verificar o permissionamento desses diretorios sem isso não adiantaria limpa-los